# In which queues are the delegate/datasource methods for collection view performed in?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, queue

I've always assumed all collectionView/ tableView delegates/ datasource methods are performed in the main queue, just want to verify.

Comment: All the delegate, datasource manipulations should always be done on the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything related to UI provided by any framework is executed in main thread and to verify do

```
print(Thread.isMainThread)
```

---

Inside any of these protocol methods , Also you can print

```
print(Thread.main)
print(Thread.current)
```

if matched then it's main thread , otherwise then it's another thread